# Why are my variables going out of scope? PHP

Tags: php

Language is PHP 5.4 on an Apache 2.2 server. It's a script being called by ajax.

```
$usr = new User();

function getMyName(){
    echo $usr->username;
}
getMyName();
```

For some reason $name is out of scope. Why would that be the case? I also tried directly calling the script with the same result. I tried use($name) to resolve, but that apparently only works with anonymous functions (closures)?

When I do this, it works but it's ridiculous:

```
$usr = new User();
$name = $usr->username;

function getMyName($n){
    echo $n;
}
getMyName($name);
```

Comment: I don't see $name in your first example? Also, how is your function supposed to access $usr if you're not passing it in via a parameter?

Comment: There is no $name in my first example, but I tried it that way also.

Every other lang I've used you don't have to pass them in. C++, Pascal, VB(S), Java ... would be within the scope in any of those languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$usr = new User();

function getMyName(){
    global $usr;
    echo $usr->username;
}
getMyName();
```

alternatively:

```
$usr = new User();

function getMyName($usr){
    echo $usr->username;
}
getMyName($usr);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to C++, and I was freaking out when my variable wasn't there :) Is there anything wrong with using globals? I've heard something about there being something wrong with using them if you don't have to.

Comment: I started to put this as an aswer, but @Merca put his up and mine just adds to his: In the first example, I see no reference to `$name`. The object $usr is outside the function, and therefor out of scope to it, but as Merca did,  you can pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ridiculous. This is how variable scope is supposed to work. You need to pass your $usr variable in as a function parameter, otherwise it'll be out of scope. Functions were designed to take in input and send back a result/output. You should stick with your second example, instead of messing around with globals...

```
$usr = new User();
$name = $usr->username;

function getMyName($n){
    echo $n;
}
getMyName($name);
```

Here's a quote from Wikipedia:

> In computer science, a subroutine, also termed procedure, function,
>   routine, method, or subprogram, is a part of source code within a
>   larger computer program that performs a specific task and is
>   relatively independent of the remaining code.

Comment: What's wrong with globals exactly? Why is it that every other language variables are scope limited by the container they run in - the variables outside the function should be available to it, but variables inside should not be available to the outside.

I'm not that far into the code yet, I might just scrap PHP and rewrite it. C++ / ISAPI - bet it outperforms PHP by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Basically, globals transport variable data from one part of your code to the other and they can cause a lot of bugs. They can also make it more difficult to debug applications. Here's a good article: http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it